# Regular Expression to find amount without trailing % sign

Tags: java, regex

Need a regular expression to get the amount (`892.33`) from the below text

```
Property Tax Allotment 3.76% 892.33 USD
```

Condition - It should not consider numbers with trailing % sign

Am trying with the below pattern

```
\\s?[0-9\\.,]{2,20}(?!\\%)\\s?
```

but getting `3.76` without % sign

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a negative lookahead for any following digits:

```
\\b[0-9.,]{2,20}(?!\\d)(?!%)\\b
```

[Live demo](https://regex101.com/r/BbxWLB/1)

Comment: Perfect. Thanks revo

Comment: Well, this regex works even for an IP address such as  192.82.1.1

Comment: Not only an IP address but also a sequence of commas. This is not a problem as long as OP's sure about the input string. @MaxZoom

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
\d+\.\d\d(?= USD)
```

One or more digits `\d+` followed by a literal dot `\.` and two more digits `\d\d`, with a positive lookahead for " USD" `(?= USD)`

It would need to be modified slightly if the fractional component of the price is optional.

[Try it online](https://regex101.com/r/aJTRjf/2).

Comment: That [includes the percentages](https://regex101.com/r/aJTRjf/3). Is that what you wanted?

Comment: wanted without $ (Condition - It should not consider numbers with trailing % sign)

Comment: Did you look at that link? That expression does consider numbers with a trailing percentage sign.

Comment: OP unintentionally is mistaking a dollar sign for a percentage.

Comment: @revo aha. Confusing when the number he *does* want is USD ;)